# Ng-options don't refresh with track by

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i want make cascade filter in Angular Js with ng-options
i have html

```
<div class="selection">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="size" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{'logSize' | translate}}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="size" class="form-control" ng-model="logbook.size" ng-options="size as size.name | translate for size in versions track by size.id"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pages" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{'logSize' | translate}}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="pages" class="form-control" ng-model="logbook.pages" ng-options="pages as pages.name | translate for pages in logbook.size.pages track by pages.id"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id="typeof" for="logSize" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{'logSize' | translate}}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="typeof" class="form-control" ng-model="logbook.typeofsiding" ng-options="typeofsiding as typeofsiding.name | translate for typeofsiding in logbook.pages.typeofsiding track by typeofsiding.id"></select>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="terms" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{'logSize' | translate}}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="terms" class="form-control" ng-model="logbook.terms" ng-options="terms as terms.name | translate for terms in logbook.typeofsiding.terms track by terms.id"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and js

```
    $scope.versions = [
{
    id: "20cm",
    name: "20 cm",
    pages: [
    {
        id: "doublesided",
        name: "Double-sided",
        typeofsiding: [
            {
                name: "Two-side",
                id: "twoside",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "QR",
                    id: "QR"
                },
                {
                    name: "Text",
                    id: "Text"
                },
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        id: "onesided",
        name: "One-sided",
        typeofsiding: [
            {
                name: "none",
                id: "none",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "QR",
                    id: "QR"
                },
                {
                    name: "Text",
                    id: "Text"
                },
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            }

        ]
    }]
},

{
    id: "15cm",
    name: "15 cm",
    pages: [
    {
        id: "doublesided",
        name: "Double-sided",
        typeofsiding: [
            {
                name: "Two-side",
                id: "twoside",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "QR",
                    id: "QR"
                },
                {
                    name: "Text",
                    id: "Text"
                },
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        id: "onesided",
        name: "One-sided",
        typeofsiding: [
            {
                name: "none",
                id: "none",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "QR",
                    id: "QR"
                },
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            }

        ]
    }]
},
{
    id: "10cm",
    name: "10 cm",
    pages: [
    {
        id: "doublesided",
        name: "Double-sided",
        typeofsiding: [
            {
                name: "fold",
                id: "fold",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "QR",
                    id: "QR"
                },
                {
                    name: "Text",
                    id: "Text"
                },
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            },
            {
                name: "Two-side",
                id: "twoside",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "QR",
                    id: "QR"
                },
                {
                    name: "Text",
                    id: "Text"
                },
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        id: "onesided",
        name: "One-sided",
        typeofsiding: [
            {
                name: "none",
                id: "none",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            }

        ]
    }]
},
{
    id: "5cm",
    name: "5 cm",
    pages: [
    {
        id: "doublesided",
        name: "Double-sided",
        typeofsiding: [
            {
                name: "fold",
                id: "fold",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "QR",
                    id: "QR"
                },
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            },
            {
                name: "Two-side",
                id: "twoside",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "QR",
                    id: "QR"
                },
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        id: "onesided",
        name: "One-sided",
        typeofsiding: [
            {
                name: "none",
                id: "none",
                terms: [
                {
                    name: "Link",
                    id: "Link"
                }]
            }

        ]
    }]
}];
```

when i use ng-option without track by it perfect but i need my id values.
When i use track by the selects don't refresh and don't work properly.
Please help me. I spend whole day at this problem.

Comment: have your tried something like `item.id as item.name for item in items` (or something along those lines)?

Comment: Yes :) but still nothing. It brokes everything.

Comment: @ajmajmajma that will break the rest of the code, because that will change the value of ng-model and set that to item.id instead of the item object.

Comment: could you please put the code to something like 'codepen' or 'plunkr' ? It will be easier to debug.

Comment: It seems to update in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/bhskndmj/). Is this like you want it?

Comment: @AWolf, thanks for that, I was about to create another fiddle before you post :)

Comment: @Awolf  I was messing around with the code in fiddle too and it all updates, except when you change the top level option. I think it has something to do with the way track by works in ng-options.

Comment: OP, I think the reason the nested options are not updated, is that all of the top level options have the same next set of options. To clarify, 20,15,10, and 5cm all have Pages doublesided and onesided, so my guess is that the way ng-options works with track by, it does not run through all nested properties to verify anything has changed, it's only checking for the property nested immediately under.

Comment: For a dirty fix, you can add ng-change to  your top level select like `<select id="size" class="form-control" ng-change="logbook.pages = undefined" ng-model="logbook.size" ng-options="size as size.name | translate for size in versions track by size.id"></select>` This will cause all nested options to be reset.

Comment: @AlexChance This not help https://jsfiddle.net/bhskndmj/2/

Comment: I am not sure what you want the behavior to be then? That causes the options to refresh, which is what I thought you needed in the question.

Comment: @AlexChance Test-case: You chose 20cm, double-sided and you have just two-side option. But if you chose 10cm you would have two-side and fold option. Also if you chose 10cm and then re-click Double-sided options fold and two-side dont refresh.

Comment: Hmmm... I see that now. I will see of another solution.